# can't find error, simple but stuck

Tags: c

Got a weird problem, I've looked this over a million times but I think my head is messing with me, just a simple short problem I'm following in the Head First C book, am getting a token or "(" required before "{" error when I try to compile and run. Can't find where?

It says on line 5 I think but yeah, anyone tell me what the problem is? I know it'll be real simple, but my brain is messing with me!

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void go_south_east(int lat, int lon);
{
    lat = lat - 1;
    lon = lon + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int latitude = 32;
    int longitude = -64;
    go_south_east(latitude, longitude);
    printf("Avast! Now at: [%i, %i]\n", latitude, longitude);

return 0;
}
```

Yes I know there's a problem with the fact that it won't point to the correct location and the value won't change once run, but that's just the idea, learning about pointers and this is the first task, but I can't get this piece to compile :(

Thanks guys, you're the best!

Comment: I always wished that (common) error was spelled out more clearly by the compiler.

Comment: @Jim I always wished that people read the error message and looked at the line number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra `;`

```
void go_south_east(int lat, int lon);
                                    ^ remove
```

it should be:

```
void go_south_east(int lat, int lon)
{                         //        ^ removed
    lat = lat - 1;
    lon = lon + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C is still a pass-by-value language. If you want a function to be able to modify its arguments, you have to pass pointers to them:

```
void foo(int *p)
{
    ++*p;
}
```

(Also note the use of the `++` increment operator, it's idiomatic to write increments and decrements like this, `lat = lat - 1;` is considered superfluously verbose.)

(Not to mention the syntax error of course, which doesn't even permit your code to compile...)

Comment: Did read what I said? lol. I know about the improvements to this code, which is what I'm reading about, I was just wondering what I did wrong in THIS piece of code which is just the first exercise in the pointers section, explaining how we need to use pointers. Thanks for the solutions guys.

Comment: And yes I know what line it was on, but wasn't sure what the error was, my bad. I'm new :)

Comment: @spergalerger Well, I'm so used to these kinds of errors :) It wasn't quite clear to me what you meant by some parts of your question, whatever. :)

Comment: @spergalerger (But feel free to accept Grijesh's answer, since he spotted your *actual* problem first.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1) 
    void go_south_east(int lat, int lon); 
Remove semicolon from above line at the end.

2) You are passing only variable value to the function.

Changes done to variable values inside function present in your code are not reflected in calling function